# Set navbar selection to class active while also having the Login link switched to Logout if signed in?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to figure a way to have "Login" be set to logout, when a user is signed in, but also having their current navbar selection be highlighted in blue?

I moved the html in the php below out of the html body. This html was repeated in every file for each page and `<a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>` was different according to the page selection. I tried to minimize my code repetition by moving it to an external file to be called in via `<?php include ("scripts/navbar.php"); ?>`.

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apwQJ.png) Here you can see Contact is blue because it's the page I'm currently on. But if a user is signed in, I want Contact to still be blue if they're currently on the Contact.php page, but to have Login changed to Log Out for the session. I have my logout script functioning correctly, but I'm not sure how to dynamically change both login to logout, while setting the selection to blue.

```
    <?php if ( ! isset($_SESSION['username'] ) ): ?>
        <div class="topnav">
      <img src="assets/images/header5.jpg">
          <a href="Signin.php">Login</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <a href="about.php">About</a>
      <a href="sample.php">Sample</a>
      <a href="fees.php">Fees</a>
      <a href="vintage.php">Vintage</a>
      <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
        <?php else: ?>
    <div class="topnav">
      <img src="assets/images/header5.jpg">
          <a href="/script/LogOut.php">Logout</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <a href="about.php">About</a>
      <a href="sample.php">Sample</a>
      <a href="fees.php">Fees</a>
      <a href="vintage.php">Vintage</a>
      <a href="services.php">Services</a>
   <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I ideally didn't want to have 6-7 different files for the navbar,

Comment: Ideally you'd use the `$_SESSION['username']` if statement to swap out just the Login/Logout text. Use another if statement to determine and set the active class based on which page the user is on. Maybe another PHP global could help you determine that.

Comment: Thank you, this was so simple I overlooked it. I just had the one list element I wanted in the php script, then included the file in the HTML element. `<div class="topnav">
<?php include ("scripts/navbar.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="topnav">
<img src="assets/images/header5.jpg">
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
<a href="Signin.php">Login</a>
<?php else : ?>
<a href="/script/LogOut.php">Logout</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="about.php">About</a>
<a href="sample.php">Sample</a>
<a href="fees.php">Fees</a>
<a href="vintage.php">Vintage</a>
<a href="services.php">Services</a>
<a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
</div>
```